# Example of Tilemill Mapbox Terrain style?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, mapbox, tilemill

I'm wading through teaching myself Tilemill and Carto CSS, with the numerous examples such as OSM Bright being very helpful. What I'm really interested in is outdoor/hiking type maps. The MapBox Terrain looks really cool, and I'd like to build off something like that. Is the MapBox Terrain Style a closely-guarded corporate secret, or is the CartoCSS used to render that available somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There's a full-fledged tutorial [for creating terrain maps with TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/terrain-data/), including CartoCSS examples.